# Prepend all SELECT variables with a string

Tags: sql

Is there a way to prepend all SELECT variables with a string without manually doing it?

In the example below, I am trying to prepend the string `col_` in front of every variable.

#### Manual Method:

```
SELECT a col_a, b col_b, c col_c FROM alphabet_table
```

#### Ideal Method (Not Actual):

```
SELECT * col_* FROM alphabet_table
```

Is there a way to do this for all variables selected with `*`?

Comment: No, this is not possible except if you use Dynamic SQL. And by *variables* you mean *columns*. I can't fathom why you might need this - you could also create a *view* with the required column aliases and select from it instead.

Comment: Please tag with which rdbms. Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SqlServer 2017+ and using dynamic sql something like this would work:

```
Declare @columns nvarchar(max)
set @columns=(
SELECT STRING_AGG(Column_Name+' col_'+Column_Name,',') as Prefixes
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'alphabet_table'
)

exec('select '+@columns+' from alphabet_table')
```